# MySQL-condition on partition size

Tags: mysql, sql

`table1` has 3 columns in my database: `id`, `category`, `timestamp`. I need to query the newest 3 rows from each category:

```
WITH ranked_rows AS
(SELECT t.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY category ORDER BY t.timestamp DESC) AS rn
FROM table1 AS t)
SELECT ranked_rows.* FROM ranked_rows WHERE rn<=3
```

now I need to add one more condition: `select only from the partitions which have at least 3 rows`. how to add this condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is another way:

```
select * from (
   SELECT t.*
      , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY category ORDER BY t.timestamp DESC) AS rn
      , count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY category) AS cnt
FROM table1 AS t
) t 
WHERE rn<=3 and cnt>= 3
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make another CTE of only the categories matching your condition, then join to that:

```
WITH ranked_rows AS
(
  SELECT t.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY category ORDER BY t.timestamp DESC) AS rn
  FROM table1 AS t
),
categories AS 
(
  SELECT category 
  FROM table1 
  GROUP BY category 
  HAVING COUNT(*) >= 3
)
SELECT r.* FROM ranked_rows AS r
JOIN categories AS c USING (category) 
WHERE r.rn <= 3;
```